# Proving that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt(\pi)$ using the expected value of standard normal variable (integral calculation)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, gamma-function, expected-value

I'm looking to prove that $\gamma$$(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt(\pi)$ using the fact that $E(Z^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}} z^2 dz$ (where $Z$ is a standard normal variable), using the fact that $\gamma$$(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{r-1}e^{-y}dy$.

The way I've gone about this is to allow $y={\frac{z^2}{2}}$ and so $z=\sqrt{2y}; dz=\frac{dz}{\sqrt(2y)}$.

Substituting these in I eventually get that $E(Z^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y} \sqrt{y} dy = 1$,

but this is where I'm getting stuck as I don't know how to bridge the gap here to

$\gamma$$(r)=\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{r-1}e^{-y}dy$.

The equations look similar, except for the $y^{r-1}$ term.

I posted this previously on the stats site but was recommended to post it here as where I'm getting stuck has to do with the manipulation of the last integral.

Thank you!

Comment: You must mean $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}.$ Where $\Gamma(1) = 0! = \Gamma(2) = 1! = 1.$ You can produce that by typing `$\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}.$`.

Comment: Hem, $y^{r-1}\leftrightarrow y^{1/2}$.

Comment: That substitution is incorrect. You need an absolute value around the $y$’s. Alternatively, you probably should change the bounds of the integral to $0$ to $\infty$ which will account for the factor of two mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397122/proving-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi-using-the-expected-value-of-st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $\sqrt{y}=y^{\frac32-1}$.

Pull the constant multiple out, and you've calculated $\Gamma(\frac32)$. Now, apply the functional equation $\Gamma(\frac32)=\frac12\Gamma(\frac12)$.

But... be careful with that constant multiple. It looks like you lost a factor of $2$ doing the substitution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you get that $\gamma (\frac{3}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} \gamma (\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: It's the standard functional equation for the gamma function: $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. That functional equation is the first thing we prove about the gamma function, and the main reason for having it at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info and your help as that was where I was getting stuck!